# Add controls for minimum password length and complexity

Tags: javascript, html, css, mysql, node.js

can someone tell me how to add controls for minimum password length and complexity
to my website

this is the database

```
CREATE TABLE Users(

id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(id),
username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
birthday DATE
);

CREATE TABLE dreams(

dream_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(dream_id),
content text NOT NULL,
user_id INT,
FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES Users(id)

);
```

I want when the users sign up and they try to create their passwords they get a message tell them that its too weak or that it has to be consisting of letters&numbers ..etc

is there something I can do through the database?
if its somewhere else please help I'm a beginner
I use nodejs-html-CSS-JavaScript
thank you.

Comment: I also want to know how to add profile photo in the database should it be in the users table? or in a separate table with a reference to each user. and what datatype should it be

Comment: This is a task for the application layer rather than the database. Maybe one should also remind that password should never be stored as plain text; hash them in the application first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery.validate in your javascript code,

```
<script>
    $("#form1").validate({
        rules:{
            password:{
                required:true,
                minlength:8
            }
        },
        messages:{
            password:{
                required:"Password is required",
                minlength:"Passowrd must be atleast 8 characters long"
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

password is the name attribute in your input field, and for picture in database you can use varbinary(max)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should set up validation to work from both the server-side and the client-side. Client-side, mostly for user experience, as a dev-savvy person can always circumvent anything in the browser. However, per your statement, you would like a nice user message and displaying that, no matter what is client-side, and this will help your users know better how to use your form. Server-side validation should also be in place to prevent bad data from being saved in your database.

In short, you will need them to work hand-in-hand. You don't need any sort of special js library for most basic validation. HTML5 will give you what you need to display many requirements without having extra javascript. However, using some kind of javascript is necessary if you don't like how HTML5 validation looks. But, I would always start by using it, because it will help your application meet accessibility standards easier and from there, you can iterate to make it look nicer by adding fancier javascript-based things on top of it.

The snip will have a warning overlay that won't happen on your website. See (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp) for more information and this same example.

```html
<form action="">
  <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd"
  pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}"
  title="Must contain at least one  number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Now on your backend, you should create a function in the code that processes the form to recheck the validation before saving it to the database along with your other DB rules. If this validation fails because somehow the user or some bug allowed the validation to be circumvented, you would send back a failure message in the form response that the front-end would catch and display after a failed attempt to save to the database. Answering how exactly to go about that would require much more information on how your app is setup.

You could also create a table in the database to store your validation rules and could pass those rules to the front-end via some kind of API so the frontend and backend functions can share the same rules and not have to hardcode the same regular expressions or whatever rule you are dealing with. In other words, a single point of truth for both validations -- the user experience check and the data integrity check.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Using Validation Password for detected Weak or Strong Password:

I have 2 example:
**This is Pure Javascript**

```js
var code = document.getElementById("password");

var strengthbar = document.getElementById("meter");
var display = document.getElementsByClassName("textbox")[0];

code.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  checkpassword(code.value);
});


function checkpassword(password) {
  var strength = 0;
  if (password.match(/[a-z]+/)) {
    strength += 1;
  }
  if (password.match(/[A-Z]+/)) {
    strength += 1;
  }
  if (password.match(/[0-9]+/)) {
    strength += 1;
  }
  if (password.match(/[$@#&!]+/)) {
    strength += 1;

  }

  if (password.length < 6) {
    display.innerHTML = "minimum number of characters is 6";
  }

  if (password.length > 12) {
    display.innerHTML = "maximum number of characters is 12";
  }

  switch (strength) {
    case 0:
      strengthbar.value = 0;
      break;

    case 1:
      strengthbar.value = 25;
      break;

    case 2:
      strengthbar.value = 50;
      break;

    case 3:
      strengthbar.value = 75;
      break;

    case 4:
      strengthbar.value = 100;
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form class="center-block">
    <input type="text" id="password" autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-lg">
    <progress max="100" value="0" id="meter"></progress>
  </form>
  <div class="textbox text-center"> password </div>
</body>
```

**This is jQuery**

```js
function ValidatePassword() {
  /*Array of rules and the information target*/
  var rules = [{
      Pattern: "[A-Z]",
      Target: "UpperCase"
    },
    {
      Pattern: "[a-z]",
      Target: "LowerCase"
    },
    {
      Pattern: "[0-9]",
      Target: "Numbers"
    },
    {
      Pattern: "[!@@#$%^&*]",
      Target: "Symbols"
    }
  ];

  //Just grab the password once
  var password = $(this).val();

  /*Length Check, add and remove class could be chained*/
  /*I've left them seperate here so you can see what is going on */
  /*Note the Ternary operators ? : to select the classes*/
  $("#Length").removeClass(password.length > 6 ? "glyphicon-remove" : "glyphicon-ok");
  $("#Length").addClass(password.length > 6 ? "glyphicon-ok" : "glyphicon-remove");
  
  /*Iterate our remaining rules. The logic is the same as for Length*/
  for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {

    $("#" + rules[i].Target).removeClass(new RegExp(rules[i].Pattern).test(password) ? "glyphicon-remove" : "glyphicon-ok"); 
    $("#" + rules[i].Target).addClass(new RegExp(rules[i].Pattern).test(password) ? "glyphicon-ok" : "glyphicon-remove");
      }
    }

    /*Bind our event to key up for the field. It doesn't matter if it's delete or not*/
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#NewPassword").on('keyup', ValidatePassword)
    });
```

```css
.glyphicon-remove {
  color: red;
}

.glyphicon-ok {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
  <input class="form-control" id="NewPassword" placeholder="New Password" type="password">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
</div>
<div id="Length" class="input glyphicon-remove">Must be at least 7 charcters</div>
<div id="UpperCase" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">Must have atleast 1 upper case character</div>
<div id="LowerCase" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">Must have atleast 1 lower case character</div>
<div id="Numbers" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">Must have atleast 1 numeric character</div>
<div id="Symbols" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">Must have atleast 1 special character</div>
```